# Why isn't my file that I saved to the workspace found in CircleCI?

Tags: circleci

I did run a pipeline where I saved a file using workspaces. The pipeline is successful.
However, when running another different pipeline, I can't find my file. What did I wrong ?

I created the file as:
[image]

Where the workspace was created as: [image]

But in the next pipeline, It simply isn't there: [image]
I did of course attach the workspace with: [image]

Comment: When you say pipelines, do you mean different jobs within a workflow, or completely separate builds?

Comment: completely separate builds. I thought that files will persist no matther what, for 15 days.

Comment: @jure's question was very sharp! As you can see from the diagram on [this page](https://circleci.com/docs/workspaces/#overview), workflows are for sharing data across jobs within a given workflow run. To share data across completely separate builds, you'll need to [use caching](https://circleci.com/docs/caching/).

Comment: @yaningo I assumed it will persist accross different builds as well, because otherwise why do the files stay 15 days ? No workflow is supposed to be that long ?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue and I resolved it by ensuring there was a link (direct/transitive) between the source and the destination job. My source job was a dead end and it had no link whatsoever with my destination job.

Here is how my failing workflow looked:

[image: Here is how my failing workflow looked]

This is explained in this article [Deep Diving into CircleCI Workspaces](https://circleci.com/blog/deep-diving-into-circleci-workspaces/)